# Could someone explain this error on fprintf() in Octave?

Tags: file, text, printf, octave, integral

I am trying to write in a text file the result of an integral, but when I run the program I get the next error.

```
error: fprintf: wrong type argument 'class'
```

Here´s my code.

```
syms x
f=x;

archivo=fopen('ejemplo.txt','w')

variable=int(f,x,1,2)

fprintf(archivo,'%f\n',variable)


fclose(archivo)
```

Could someone explain whats wrong?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Comment: `variable` is a symbolic variable, not a floating-point value, as expected by “%f”. Cast it to `double`.