# Integration in Octave between float point

Tags: double, warnings, octave, numerical-integration, sym

I am trying to calculate the integral between two float points. The programm can do it, but it sends this next messagge

> warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"

This is my code

```
i=2.5;

syms x y

f=((2*x-1)/10)*((2*y-1)/10)/(x+y);

variable=double(int(int(f,x,i,1),y,i,1));
```

is there anyway to do it whithout that inconvenient?

Comment: Please show us your code. It depends on which constants you’re passing in, how to do it properly. Also, consider using numerical integration instead of symbolic integration if that gives you sufficient precision.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're casting to double at the end because of the answer you got to your other question: [Could someone explain this error on fprintf() in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932383/could-someone-explain-this-error-on-fprintf-in-octave), where casting your answer to double was suggested so that you could pass it to fprintf.

Octave is giving you a warning about combining floating type and symbolic numbers. This is a potential concern because symbolic numbers are stored 'exactly', while floating points may not be, depending on their value.  But it is only a warning. Not recommended, but you can disable warnings.  See https://docs.octave.org/latest/Enabling-and-Disabling-Warnings.html

The problem is occurring because you are using a float value 2.5 in your integration limits.  To avoid the issue, define it as a symbolic value:

```
pkg load symbolic;

syms x, y;

i = sym("2.5")
i = (sym) 5/2

variable = int(int(f,x,i,1),y,i,1)
variable = (sym)

    11*log(5)   log(2)    33   28*log(7/2)
  - --------- - ------ + --- + -----------
        30       150     200        75

variable = double (variable)
variable = 0.037950
```

As suggested in a comment above, if you have no need for a symbolic answer to your question, and you're casting it immediately to a floating point number, you might find it easier to do numeric integration instead.  That could be accomplished for your problem as follows:

```
# define equation as a function. Note use of .* and ./ 'elementwise' 
# operators to avoid unwanted matrix multiplication/division.
f = @(x,y) ((2*x-1)/10).*((2*y-1)/10)./(x+y); 

# Solve the 2D integral, returning a numeric result
variable = integral2 (f, 2.5, 1, 2.5, 1)
variable = 0.037950
```